# Keras.NET how can i specify the python interpreter used

Tags: python, keras, .net

I'm trying to use Keras.NET to implement predictions of a keras model in a WPF application. The model itself was trained with keras in a python environement on another maching. However to write a nice GUI, I now decided to try an use Keras.NET. So I installed Python3.10 on this machine and got Keras.NET from nuget package manager.

However, when importing the model with...

```
var model = Keras.Models.Model.LoadModel(@"F:\1656570370\saved_model.pb");
```

I used to get an error, because the python38.dll could not be found. To fix this I installed python3.8 in system wide scope.
The next error message is now that "tensorflow" is not found. However, I do not like to install python packages in system wide scope. I would like to use a virtual environment for that.

Does anyone know how to specify the exact Python interpreter to be used by Keras.NET?